# jupyter-lab installed but jupyter doesn't see it

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, jupyter-lab, kepler.gl

I have jupyter-lab installed via pip3 with Python 3.8.10 on Ubuntu 20.04. I've been using it for months, but noticed some problems getting KeplerGL to render maps in it. While trouble-shooting this, I ran `jupyter --version` to see which version of jupyterlab I have installed (KeplerGL setup varies based on jupyter-lab version), and mysteriously, it says:

`jupyter lab      : not installed`

Quite odd, because I have it open right now; I launched it from the command line like this:

`$ jupyter-lab`

I ran `pip3 install jupyterlab` for good measure, and got a bunch of "requirement already satisfied" messages. I suspect this has something to do with my inability to render KeplerGL, but my main purpose for this inquiry is figuring out why Jupyter isn't seeing jupyter-lab.

Comment: Have you followed the installation steps? https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/installation.html

Comment: I did. as the instructions say, run "pip install jupyterlab". I'm using Python3, so I used pip3. I also ran "sudo pip3 install jupyterlab".

Comment: hmm, weird. The same command on macOS gives `jupyter lab      : 3.1.12`. I suggest checking issues in the Ubuntu package bug tracker. You can also try https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: I'm confused by your recommendation to check Ubuntu package buck tracker. I'm not using an Ubuntu package- I installed using pip3.

Comment: Sorry, you're right this has nothing to do with Ubuntu packages then

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure everything is installed in the same environment?

Comment: I am using the base install of Python3; not using any virtual environments.